# Octave to MATLAB code conversion

Tags: matlab, octave

Please check the code below :

```
if strcmp(pulse_mode, 'nrz_2_dpsk') || strcmp(pulse_mode, 'rz_2_dpsk')

      N = size(tx_data,2);

      tx_data *= 2;
      tx_data -= 1;

      [tx_signal_time, tx_signal_data] = create_tx_signal(tx_data, impulse_shaper, pulse_mode, t1, nb_points);
      tx_signal_data = tx_signal_data / sqrt(2);

    else
      [tx_signal_time,tx_signal_data] = create_tx_signal(tx_data, impulse_shaper, pulse_mode, t1, nb_points);

    end
```

What is the equivalent syntax in MATLAB for this Octave code?

Comment: did you encounter errors in running this in Octave? Care to elaborate on those errors?

Comment: @Dan  his problem is the inverse. He has code written in Octave that does not work in Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is predominantly the same.  The only thing you need to change are the **in-place** operators (i.e. `tx_data *= 2; tx_data -= 1;`.  You have to explicitly define the operations, so you would have to do this:

```
tx_data = tx_data * 2;
tx_data = tx_data - 1;
```

Other than that, there isn't a need to change anything, unless you want to change the `create_tx_signal` function too.  We don't have the source for that so the buck stops here for me.

Good luck!